# How to custom textInput to be sure user can add only numbers no comma, dot or other symbols?

Tags: react-native, textinput

What can I add in my textInput to be sure that the user can write only numbers and no comma, dot or other symbols?

```
          <TextInput
            onChangeText={text => setTextInputValue(text)}
            value={textInputValue}
            placeholder=" perso"
            keyboardType="numeric"
            style={styles.inputRE1}
          />
```

Comment: add `type="number"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can replace text with regular expression on onChangeText.

```js
onChangeText={text => setTextInputValue(text.replace(/[^0-9]/g, ''))}
```

`/[^0-9]/g` regex will remove every character other than numbers.

Answer (score 1):

As simple as possible :
1- add (keypress)="numberOnly($event)" event on your TextInput.

2- use the code to just enter the numbers  :

```
 numberOnly(event): boolean {
  const charCode = event.which ? event.which : event.keyCode;
  if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)) {
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

Comment: Sorry I put a wrong tag, I need it for react native

Comment: It's Ok. I thought you need it for the react